# How to encode base64 via command line in macOS/OS X?

Tags: macos, command-line, bash, encoding, base64

Is there a terminal command in macOS/OS X which will base64 encode a file or stdin?

Comment: Be aware that although the base64-encoding syntax is consistent from one OS to another, the base64-decoding syntax is either `base64 -d` or `base64 -D` depending on your operating system. OSX uses `-D`.

Comment: @ChrisJohnson If used in concert with `openssl` the flag for decoding is `-d` on OS X (10.10 Yosemite).

Comment: Simply `echo -n password | base64` in your MacOS Terminal; and `echo -n password | base64 -D` to decode.

Answer (score 427, accepted):

`openssl` can do this for you, and it's all installed with OS X by default; no need to install darwinports.

```
$ openssl base64 -in <infile> -out <outfile>
```

Without the `-in` option reads from stdin

Comment: Use `openssl base64 < path/to/file.png | tr -d '\n' | pbcopy` or `cat path/to/file.png | openssl base64 | tr -d '\n' | pbcopy` to skip writing to a file and just copy the base64-encoded output to the clipboard without the line breaks.

Comment: And use a `-d` flag to decode.

Comment: In mac, To base64 encode a string: `openssl base64 -e <<< ram` and to decode: `openssl base64 -d <<< cmFtCg==`

Comment: is there an option to output the base64-encoded string in the terminal?

Comment: never mind, I found it: `openssl base64 < path/to/file` should work fine.

Comment: @mathias if you want no newlines `openssl base64 [-e] -A` does that. + @kenny on decode if input does not have newline every 76 chars at most, including the no-newlines case I just stated, you need `-d -A` or you will get missing or corrupted data *with no error message* (although there is a pending bug report which may result in a fix to that).

Comment: @Ram, `openssl base64 -e <<< ram` actually encodes 4 bytes, including a trailing line feed; see `hexdump <<< ram`.

Comment: I had to use -D instead of the lowercase -d

Comment: Taking @MathiasBynens even further: `pbpaste | openssl base64 -A | pbcopy` to automagically transform what's on your clipboard into base64. (added -A)

Answer (score 219):

OpenSSL can be used more succinctly:

```
echo -n 'input' | openssl base64
```

`echo -n ->` must be used, or encoding will be done including new line character.

Or:

```
openssl base64 <ENTER> [type input] <CTRL+D>
```

Comment: The "echo" solution adds a LF (line feed) char to the end of the input string, though. Better use: echo -n 'input'

Comment: And even a bit more succinct `openssl base64 <<< input`

Comment: Or just use `base64` without `openssl`. Either way, I need to press Ctrl+D twice. And beware, @Garret: in Bash, with or without `openssl`, `openssl base64 <<< superuser` and `openssl base64 <<< "superuser"` **erroneously** yield `c3VwZXJ1c2VyCg==`, as the "here string" then still includes a line feed! ([Apparently](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2015-02/msg00096.html) not only in Bash, but also in zsh, ksh and yash. See `hexdump <<< superuser`. The Base64 result should be `c3VwZXJ1c2Vy`.)

Comment: @Arjan I'd hesitate to use the word "erroneously" - as you pointed out, the  here-string includes a line feed, but for good reason - http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20157/why-does-a-bash-here-string-add-a-trailing-newline-char . `echo -n` is preferred if you don't need the newline. It's certainly something to be aware of.

Comment: @Steve, indeed, it's not `openssl base64` nor Bash that are to blame. But it surely is not the expected outcome when encoding the word `input`, so I wanted to ensure the "erroneously" is seen by future readers ;-)

Comment: You could use `printf` in place of `echo -n`

Answer (score 102):

Try using:

```
base64 -i <in-file> -o <outfile>
```

It should be available by default on OS X.

Comment: Add `--decode` to reverse the process from base64 to normal.

Comment: This is better for encoding for SVG because it creates one line. This is cleaner than the output from `openssl base64`. Thanks!

Comment: I didn't want to use files so you can do `echo -n "something" | base64`

Answer (score 94):

On macOS I always use:

```
echo -n "STRING" | base64
```

`-n` is to avoid a new line character on the end of the line.

Comment: This also works on Windows if you're running Cmder.

Comment: This works for me in mac

Answer (score 65):

`base64` command is available by default on my OS X 10.9.4.

You can use `base64 <<< string` and `base64 -D <<< string` to encode and decode a string in the terminal, or `base64 -in file` and `base64 -D -in file` to encode and decode a file.

Comment: Do you have an example? I get `Invalid characer in input stream` when using `<<<`...I have tried with `"`, `'` and nothing around the string.

Comment: @Jonas What shell are you in? You can use this in bash and zsh.

Comment: Ah, nevermind, it works!

Comment: Please note `base64 <<< cat` is equivalent to `echo cat|base64`, not `echo -n cat|base64`.  Basically the automatic linefeed will be added to the base64 encoded string, and that might not be what you want.

Answer (score 17):

Since Python is provided with OS X by default, you can use it as below:

```
$ echo FOO | python -m base64
Rk9PCg==
$ echo Rk9PCg== | python -m base64 -d
FOO
```

Or install `coreutils` via [Brew](https://brew.sh/) (`brew install coreutils`) which will provide `base64` command:

```
$ echo FOO | base64
Rk9PCg==
$ echo Rk9PCg== | base64 -d
FOO
```

Answer (score 8):

#### Python

Python3 comes preinstalled on all modern macs and linuces nowadays. The `base64` module in the standard library exposes a cli interface (see `python3 -m base64 -h`)

<kbd>*Encode*</kbd>

```bash
# encode /etc/hosts to hosts.b64 in the current folder
# passing -e is optional since it's the default operation
python3 -m base64 -e < /etc/hosts > hosts.b64

# encode a literal string to stdout (❗️appends a new line char)
python3 -m base64 <<< 'nobody expects the spanish inq..'
# OUT: bm9ib2R5IGV4cGVjdHMgdGhlIHNwYW5pc2ggaW5xLi4K
```

<kbd>*Decode*</kbd>

```bash
# decode hosts.b64 to hosts.txt
python3 -m base64 -d < hosts.b64 > hosts.txt
```

The python code in case you need to script it from python:

*Encode a file*:

```sh
base64data = open('myfile.jpg','rb').read().encode('base64')
open('myfile.txt','w').write(base64data)
```

*Encode a byte string without including the trailing new line:*

```python
import binascii 
encoded = binascii.b2a_base64(b'nobody expects..', newline=False)
print(encoded)
# OUT: b'bm9ib2R5IGV4cGVjdHMuLg=='

# alternative solution 
import base64
encoded = base64.standard_b64encode(b'nobody expects..')
print(encoded)
# OUT: b'bm9ib2R5IGV4cGVjdHMuLg=='
```

*Decode a file*:

```python
data = open('myfile.b64').read().decode('base64')
open('myfile.jpg','wb').write(data)
```

#### OpenSSL

```sh
# encode to base64 (on OSX use `-output`)
openssl base64 -in myfile.jpg -output myfile.jpg.b64

# encode to base64 (on Linux use `-out`)
openssl base64 -in myfile.jpg -out myfile.jpg.b64


# decode from base64 (on OSX `-output` should be used)
openssl base64 -d -in myfile.jpg.b64 -output myfile.jpg

# decode from base64 (on Linux `-out` should be used)
openssl base64 -d -in myfile.jpg.b64 -out myfile.jpg
```

Omitting the `-out`/`-output... filename` will print to stdout.

You can also pass the input data as a stream in a OS-agnostic way, e.g.

```bash
# encode /etc/hosts to hosts.b64
openssl base64 < /etc/hosts > hosts.b64

# decode hosts64.b64 to hosts.txt
openssl base64 -d < hosts.b64 > hosts.txt

# decode raw data to stdout (don't use with binary files)
openssl base64 -d < hosts.b64
```

#### Base64

Another out of the box utility commonly available on both mac and Lunux:

```
# encode to base64
base64 < myfile.jpg > myfile.jpg.b64

# decode from base64 (OSX) (note the uppercase '-D', '-d' might also be accepted newer OS's)
base64 -D < myfile.jpg.b64 > myfile.jpg

# decode from base64 (Linux) (note the lowercase 'd')
base64 -d < myfile.jpg.b64 > myfile.jpg
```

Answer (score 8):

You can also pipe it right to the clipboard (at least on mac):

```
openssl base64 -in [filename] | pbcopy
```

Comment: golfing: `base64 < [filename] | pbcopy`

Comment: Nice idea! `xclip -sel clip` would be the equivalent to `pbcopy` in X11.

Answer (score 7):

In terms of speed, I would use OpenSSL followed by Perl, followed by `uuencode`.  In terms of portability, I would use `uuencode` followed by Perl followed by openssl (If you care about reusing the code on as many other UNIX like stock platforms as possible). Be careful though because not all UNIX variants support the `-m` switch (If I recall correctly, AIX does, HP/UX does, Solaris doesn't).

```sh
$ time perl -MMIME::Base64 -e 'undef $/;while(<>){print encode_base64($_);}' \
> out.jpg 1>filename.b64
real    0m0.025s

$ time uuencode -m -o filename.b64 out.jpg filename_when_uudecoded.txt
real    0m0.051s

$  time openssl base64 -in out.jpg -out filename.b64 
real    0m0.017s
```

Use the `-m` switch to uuencode `file_in.txt` per base64 as specified by [RFC1521](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1521.txt) and write it to `filename.b64` (with `filename_when_uudecoded.tx`t as the default filename when decoded):

```sh
uuencode -m -o filename.b64 file_in.txt filename_when_uudecoded.txt
```

STDIN example:

```sh
cat file_in.txt | uuencode -m -o filename.b64 filename_when_uudecoded.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

In addition to [Steve Folly's answer](https://superuser.com/a/120815/167207), when encoding in stdin mode, to avoid passing extra newlines, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> twice to end input without any additional newlines.

The output will show right after the same line.

For example:

```bash
$ openssl base64 <kbd>Enter</kbd>
input<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd><kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>aW5wdXQ=
```

Alternatively, you could use `printf`:

```bash
$ printf 'input' | openssl base64
aW5wdXQ=
```

Comment: You meant to say encoding, right?

Comment: @nethero - yes, corrected.

Answer (score 3):

```
uuencode -m [-o output_file] [file] name
```

Where *name* is the name to display in the encoded header.

Example:

```
cat docbook-xsl.css | uuencode -m docbook-xsl.css
```

or

```
uuencode -m -o docbook-xsl.css.b64 docbook-xsl.css docbook-xsl.css
```

Comment: `uuencode` is not the encoding as `base64`

Answer (score 2):

For some reason, `echo -n <data> | openssl base64` added a newline in the middle of my base64 data. I assume it was because my base64 data was really long.

Using `echo -n <data> | base64` to encode and `echo -n <base64-ed data> | base64 -D` to decode worked fine.

Comment: nb: on my nix, i had to use -d

    echo -n c29tZXVzZXI6c29tZXBhc3N3b3Jk | base64 -d

someuser:somepassword

Answer (score 1):

There is Perl plus MIME::Base64:

```
perl -MMIME::Base64 -e 'undef $/;while(<>){print encode_base64($_);}'
```

This comes pre-installed.  You can specify separate files on the command line (or supply the data on standard input); each file is separately encoded.  You can also do:

```
perl -i.txt -MMIME::Base64 -e 'undef $/;while(<>){print encode_base64($_);}' file1
```

This backs up file1 to file1.txt, and writes the Base-64 encoded output over the original file.

Answer (score 1):

A simple NodeJS version:

```
node -e "process.stdout.write(new Buffer(process.argv[1]).toString('base64'))" "Hello world!"
```

Comment: I don't think this is a better answer as `openssl` (and now `base64`) come with the OS.

Comment: At the risk of splitting hairs — and, I’m aware that this criticism applies to a couple of the other answers, as well — the question asked how to encode ***a file*** or ***stdin***. If I’m not mistaken, your answer shows only how to encode a string.

Answer (score 1):

### Cross-platform solutions

We compiled a list of cross-platform shell commands to encode a file as base64. The following commands take an input file (named `deploy.key` in examples) and convert it to base64 without any newline wrapping. The base64 output is printed to the terminal via stdout.

```sh
# For systems with openssl
openssl base64 -A -in=deploy.key

# For systems with Python (2 or 3) installed
python -c "import base64; print(base64.standard_b64encode(open('deploy.key', 'rb').read()).decode())"

# For Windows or Linux systems that have the GNU coreutils base64 command
base64 --wrap=1000000 deploy.key

# For macOS systems
base64 --break=1000000 deploy.key
```

To redirect the output to a file, append  `> base64-encoded.txt` (using a file name of your choosing).

These commands were prototyped as part of this [pull request](https://github.com/manubot/rootstock/pull/243) where we wanted cross-platform shell commands to base64 encode an SSH private key to remove newlines.

Answer (score 1):

There are many great answers already and mine does basically the same thing except the secret is never shown in the terminal.

I created these two aliases to encode a string from my clipboard and the encoded string is copied to my clipboard. The same applies to decoding:

```bash
alias decode='pbpaste | base64 --decode | pbcopy'
alias encode='pbpaste | base64 | pbcopy'
```

Answer (score 0):

`recode` should do the trick for you

```
recode ../b64 < file.txt > file.b64
```

`recode` is available for OS X via [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/).

Comment: There's nothing built in?

Comment: @Josh - there is - openssl

Comment: MacPorts does not come with any OS X distribution. There are plenty of other options that do. For instance just `base64` command.

Answer (score 0):

If you are base64 encoding a font file, you can do this:

```
base64 my-webfont.ttf > my-webfont.b64.ttf.txt
```

I use this on a Mac (10.10) all the time.

**Note**: There will be no linebreaks.

Answer (score 0):

On Mac, you can simply encode and decode the current clipboard contents to/from base64 with:

1. Encode to base64:

   ```sh
   pbpaste | base64
   ```
2. Decode from base64:

   ```sh
   pbpaste | base64 --decode
   ```