# Batch encode multiple webfont files into a CSS file?

Tags: macos, fonts, encoding, base64

I want to batch encode several .otf font files into a single CSS file. To my understanding, base64 embedded .otf fonts can be read by most browsers. Since Font-Squirrel's @font-face generator doesn't support direct base64 encoding of .otf files, I'll have to encode the fonts myself.

I found [this method](https://superuser.com/questions/120796/os-x-base64-encode-via-command-line) of using openssl in the OS X terminal to base64 encode files one at a time--and that only outputs them to individual files.  Is there a way to batch encode them straight into a single CSS file?

Comment: This would go well on webmasters.se

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out http://www.spritebaker.com.

*Right now, SpriteBaker only encodes the first web-font file specified by each 'src' attribute in a @font-face declaration.  That shouldn't be a problem.  If you're batch encoding web-font files into CSS, you should only encode one web-font file per CSS file.  Then you should deliver a targeted CSS file to each browser.