# Standard Unix tool for decoding base64?

Tags: unix, debian, base64

I have variously depended on `metamail` and `munpack` in the past, but both of these are suffering from bit rot.  `metamail` has been removed from Debian, and `mpack` looks like it's about to be removed.

I have a package of mine which wants to depend on a base64 decoder.  I can include my own Perl one-liner, of course, but I'm getting the feeling there must already be a package which is (1) resasonably standard (including, but not limited to, being available as a package for major distributions) and (2) not part of a larger package with a different purpose, such as Emacs or Subversion.  I suppose if there's something in Coreutils that would be fine, though... Am I missing something obvious?

There are stand-alone tools like [John Walker's base64](http://www.fourmilab.ch/webtools/base64/) which fail on (1) and tools like [uudeview](http://www.fpx.de/fp/Software/UUDeview/) which turn out to do all kinds of nice things, but not the simple straightforward task of encoding and decoding a piece of base64 data.  So far, my best bet looks like [recode](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/recode/recode_60.html) although I would prefer to use something else (`iconv` does most of what it does, with a neater interface and less wacky defaults).

... [I see now](https://superuser.com/questions/120796/os-x-base64-encode-via-command-line) that `openssl` has this functionality, but it's precisely the sort of oddball dependency I'd like to avoid, although I guess it's a reasonable assumption that it will be installed on many sites for other reasons already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try `base64` from the GNU coreutils package ?
http://packages.debian.org/stable/coreutils

> Specifically, this package includes: arch **base64** [...]

Simple, effective and available on a large variety of platforms.

Comment: Whoa, thanks, indeed I was overlooking something obvious!

Comment: The coreutils on my system did not actually include `base64` in the package descriotion, although I suppose I can only lay part of the blame on Debian bug #535458: http://bugs.debian.org/535458